# How to execute nested Perl commands in same line

Tags: perl

I am new to perl  , Is it any way to write nested perl commands in single line like below (shell)

```
echo "I am  `uname -n` and today is `date`"
```

I tried like below ; but not working

```
my $i=0 ;
print "$i++\n" ;
print "localtime()" ;
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What is the expected output?

Comment: See [Quote and Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for details on what interpolates and what doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only interpolate variables into double-quoted strings.  But those variables can be anonymous, allowing you to provide an expression to generate them.  This looks like this:

```
my $i = 0;
print "Number ${\($i++)} date ${\scalar localtime}";
```

You can also use `@{[ some-expression ]}` instead of `${\ some-expression }`.  In either case, you have an expression and you create a reference to its value (or in the former case, to an anonymous array containing it), and then dereference it in the string.  The expression will be in list context, so you may need to add `scalar`, as above.

Comment: Thank you ysth; this is what I expected.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it any way to write nested perl commands in single line like below (shell)

Of course you can.

```
print "I am " . `uname -n` . "and today is " . `date`;
```

Perl's backtick operator (`) doesn't work inside double quotes (`""`). So, the string "I am ", the output of `uname -n`, the string "and today is " and the output of `date` are joined by dot operator (`.`).

I don't understand what the latter part of your question means in relation to the former part (and I think ysth has already answered to it).